# Postfix causing a fatal error in file reconfiguring not working either

Tags: 18.04, server, email, postfix

I am at a loss with this issue, I installed a new server setup from Vultr, and installed 18.04 Ubuntu in it, I just realised I cannot send any emails using the PHP `mail` function.

The error that it shows using `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` is:

```
Feb 25 22:43:11 site postfix/sendmail[20810]: fatal: /etc/postfix/mai                                                                                       n.cf, line 1: missing '=' after attribute name: "inet_interfaces# See /usr/share                                                                                       /postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version"
```

And the main file is:

**main.cf file:**

```
inet_interfaces# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks_permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = debian
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $myhostname 
relayhost = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

But I don't see any error like it suggests with `inet_interfaces` can anyone see something I can't?

Because it's a fatal error I assume that's why I cannot get any messages sent. I have reconfigured postfix a few times and there is always an error shown.

Comment: It looks like that first `inet_interfaces` is just some spurious text that got inserted before the first comment character `#` when someone was editing the file

Comment: That is strange, that was auto-generated on setup too, that was it, thank you :)